# Getting the value of self via reflection

Tags: c#, string, reflection

I've seen a few questions similar to this one, but none of them have asked what I'm trying to get at.  Basically, given a string, I want to get the value of that string via reflection.

I know it sounds weird, but I'm writing a general method to dump all of the public properties of an object, and string is a special case in that its value is really the same as the concatenated character array it's made up of.

So, my code is thus:

```
var obj = "foo";
var props = obj.GetType().GetProperties();

// I now have two properties -- length and a character array
foreach (var prop in props)
{
   if (prop.PropertyType.IsArray || prop.GetIndexParameters().Length > 0)
   {
      lines.Add(tabs + prop.Name + "(array)");
      lines.Add(tabs + "\t" + prop.GetValue(target, new object[] { 0 }));
   }
   else
      Console.WriteLine(prop.Name + ": " + prop.GetValue(obj, null));
}
```

This outputs the following:

```
Chars(array)
        f
Length: 3
```

That's all well and good, but is there a way to get the actual "foo" value out of this without resorting to going through the array and concatenating it?

Thanks!

-Ari

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (obj is string)
  Console.WriteLine(obj);
else
    ... use reflection
```

Comment: Heh.  I'm smacking myself for not having thought of that. :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just cast it back to `string`.